# DateTime toString Conversion error

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0

when i run the following code:

```
 DateTime.ParseExact("03-08-2013", "dd-mm-yyyy", null).ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy")
```

I get "03-jan-2013"

why does it convert **august** to **january**?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Lowercase `mm` means minute instead of month, so this should work as desired:

```
DateTime.ParseExact("03-08-2013", "dd-MM-yyyy", null).ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy")
```

Output: `03-Aug-2013`

Comment: No, the former means the 8th minute in 2013 and the latter the 8th month.

Answer (score 0):

You have "MMM" in the ToString() method, which means you will get a 3-letter month abbreviation. See a helpful article on the topic at http://www.csharp-examples.net/string-format-datetime/.